# Highcharts with Rails

Tags: ruby, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I'm trying to use the [Lazy High Charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) gem, but not having luck displaying the chart. The Javascript that is generated looks correct, but for some reason the chart isn't displaying in the div.

Here's the JS that is generated in the browser:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
              var onload = window.onload;
              window.onload = function(){
                if (typeof onload == "function") onload();
                        var options = { "title": { "text": "Population vs GDP For 5 Big Countries [2009]" },"legend": { "align": "right","verticalAlign": "top","y": 75,"x": -50,"layout": "vertical" },"xAxis": { "categories": [ "United States","Japan","China","Germany","France" ] },"yAxis": [ { "title": { "text": "GDP in Billions","margin": 70 } },{ "title": { "text": "Population in Millions" },"opposite": true } ],"tooltip": { "enabled": true },"credits": { "enabled": false },"plotOptions": { "areaspline": {  } },"chart": { "defaultSeriesType": "column","renderTo": "orders_chart" },"subtitle": {  },"series": [{ "name": "GDP in Billions","yAxis": 0,"data": [ 14119,5068,4985,3339,2656 ] },{ "name": "Population in Millions","yAxis": 1,"data": [ 310,127,1340,81,65 ] }] };

            window.chart_orders_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

              };
            })()
    </script>
<div id="orders_chart"></div>
```

Here's what is in the view:

```
<%= high_chart("orders_chart", @chart) %>
```

Here's the controller code:

```
def graph_orders

    @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.title(:text => "Population vs GDP For 5 Big Countries [2009]")
      f.xAxis(:categories => ["United States", "Japan", "China", "Germany", "France"])
      f.series(:name => "GDP in Billions", :yAxis => 0, :data => [14119, 5068, 4985, 3339, 2656])
      f.series(:name => "Population in Millions", :yAxis => 1, :data => [310, 127, 1340, 81, 65])

      f.yAxis [
        {:title => {:text => "GDP in Billions", :margin => 70} },
        {:title => {:text => "Population in Millions"}, :opposite => true},
      ]

      f.legend(:align => 'right', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 75, :x => -50, :layout => 'vertical',)
      f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"column"})
    end

end
```

Here's what is in the application layout:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lono Orders</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style media="screen" type="text/css">

    #orders_chart{
        width: 700px;
        height: 500px;
    }

  </style>
<body>

    <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's what my application.js looks like:

```
//= require highcharts
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't show because it works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baecd/). What does your `application.js` look like?

Comment: Make sure `jquery` and `highcharts/highcharts` are both required in `application.js`

Comment: Yup, both are required. I added the contents of 'application.js' above

Comment: Also, what kind of errors do you have in JavaScript console? It will help us a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this

```
//= require highcharts
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

To

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

You need to require `jQuery` first otherwise `highcharts` will not work correctly as the extensions cannot be defined because `$` is undefinded. Also when I include `highcharts` in my js it is `highcharts/highcharts` and I am using it in 3 different applciations right now without issue.